# Authlib - Oauth2 Server - how to accept json client credentials?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm doing an integration with a company, and have little control over their client side. code In this case, I have to implement an Oauth2 server and support their specific integration. They want to use client_credentials, but instead of sending the `client_id`, `client_secret`, and other fields as form data, they want to send it as JSON.

For authlib, this is almost the `client_secret_post` authentication, except the source data shouldn't be request.form, it should be request.data. Does anyone have any tips on creating a custom authentication for the authlib Oauth2 server side?

This question is similar, but from the client perspective: [Request oAuth token with POST and json body in authlib possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464073/request-oauth-token-with-post-and-json-body-in-authlib-possible)